# Rails 6, Devis: How to confirm user after successful email confirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-confirmable

I working on a app with `Rails 6`, `React` `Devise` & `GraphQl` & `devise-token_authenticatable` for authentication.

I'm trying to confirm the user after they successfully confirm their email. After searching and finding some possible answers I have tried this:
in devise>> confirmation_controller.rb

```
class Devise::ConfirmationsController < DeviseController

  protected

    # The path used after confirmation.
    def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
      if signed_in?(resource_name)
        redirect_to app_root_url
      else

        resource.confirm!
        redirect_to "#{request.base_url}/app/login", notice: "Email confirmed!"
      end
    end

end
```

But this doesn't work as expected.

I also tried the following without any luck:

```
def after_confirmation
  self.confirm!
end
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks for your time

Comment: You literally don't have to do anything. Just make sure you've added `:confirmable` to devise in your model, run the migration and you're good to go. The instructions are pretty straightforward - https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-:confirmable-to-Users

Comment: Thanks! I do have `:confirmable` enabled in the user model. Except I have `skip: :sessions` in my routes.rb file due to my setup (`devise_for :users, skip: :sessions, controllers: { confirmations: 'users/confirmations' }
`). This may have something to do with it. I have to find a different way to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out finally. Here's my solution. I just updated the users `confirmed_at` attribute in `Users::ConfirmationsController#show` action.

```
class Users::ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  # GET /resource/confirmation/new
  # def new
  #   super
  # end

  # POST /resource/confirmation
  # def create
  #   super
  # end

  # GET /resource/confirmation?confirmation_token=abcdef
  def show
    @user = User.find_by_confirmation_token(params[:confirmation_token])
    @user.update(confirmed_at: Time.now.utc)
    # super
  end
end
```

In routes.rb
`devise_for :users, skip: :sessions, controllers: { confirmations: 'users/confirmations' }`

Comment: could have used  confirm dedicated method with `@user.confirm`